# Doing slideToggle and toggleClass at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a slideToggle and a toggleClass at the same time:

**css**

```
li ul { display: none; }
```

**html**

```
<li>
    <div class="group"><i class="arrow_maximize"></i> Title</div>
    <ul>
        <li>anything</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**js**

```
'click .group': function (event) {
        $(event.currentTarget).next('ul').slideToggle(200);
        $(event.currentTarget).children('i').toggleClass('arrow_minimize');
}
```

What I try to get is:

1. Clicking on `.group` will slideDown the `ul`; at the same time the class of `i` should be changed to 'arrow_minimize'.
2. Clicking again should set it back: slideUp of `ul`, change class of `i` to 'arrow_maximize'

Comment: ...but what is the problem?

Comment: The class isn't changing as needed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `toggleClass` you also need to specify the other class which the element already has:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.group').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle(200);
    $(this).children('i').toggleClass('arrow_minimize arrow_maximize');
  });
});
```

```css
li ul { display: none }
i.arrow_maximize:before { content: "\25ba" }
i.arrow_minimize:before { content: "\25bc" }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <div class="group"><i class="arrow_maximize"></i> Title</div>
    <ul>
        <li>anything</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Oh, that's quite simple... Sorry for this bad question